# Please tell me if this function is well defined

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Is the function $f:[\Bbb Z]_p\to[\Bbb Z]_p$ given by $f([n]_p)=[n^2]_p$ well defined? Explain.

How do I tell if this function is well defined? If possible please give me number examples at least. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To test if the function is well defined, you need to make sure any element in the equivalence class $[n]_p$ (i.e. $n + kp, k \in \mathbb{Z}$) gets mapped to some element in the equivalence class $[n^2]_p$.

Comment: What is n+kp supposed to be? You are saying an integer plus a multiple times p, but what is p and how does that relate to n^2?

Comment: Presumably $[\mathbb{Z}]_p$ means the integers mod $p$? If not, I've misunderstood and I apologise. Otherwise, note that integers are in the same equivalence class mod $p$ if they differ by a multiple of $p$. For instance, 0, 2 and 6 all lie in the same equivalence class mod 2 as they differ by multiples of 2.

Comment: ok so I believe I know what you are trying to do and I might have an answer, so tell me if I have the right idea going or not. 

we know that m = n (mod p) we can assume pk = m-n

using this kind of logic we can do for this problem something like 
n(mod p)
pk = n
pk = n^2

Im probably way off...

Comment: You started out in the right direction, but I'm not sure where you went from there. Consider $m, n$ such that $[m]_p = [n]_p$. Then indeed $m = n + kp$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $f$ is well defined, then it should be true that $[f(n)]_p = [f(m)]_p = [f(n + kp)]_p$. Can you show this?

Comment: In terms of this problem, would it be showing n^2 = (n+kp) as correct? and if so by what means? or do i have the wrong idea again?

Comment: $f(n+kp) = [(n+kp)^2]_p$, so you would need to show that $n^2$ and $(n+kp)^2$ lie in the same equivalence class mod $p$ (in other words, that they differ by a multiple of $p$).

Comment: Can you guide me where to go, so do i set n^2 = (n+kp)^2 and try to isolate the p in this equation then relate it back to n = n+kp. Sorry for asking you so many questions and thank you for your help so far!

Comment: If we expand both sides there, we get $n^2$ on one side and $n^2 + 2kpn + k^2p^2$ on the other. Notice that both these numbers differ only by a multiple of $p$. So we are done, and $f$ is indeed well-defined! Out of interest, what is the context of your question here?

Comment: Ok, I get it, thank you very much, This is a multi part homework question for my discrete math class and using the information you gave me I believe that I have the solution to the next part C. This is the full question and my answer to part C, let me know if you think I did it correctly :D. [pictures here](http://imgur.com/a/K8LRi)

Comment: No worries about the help! I'll write out a complete answer a little later, and hopefully clear up any conceptual difficulties that remain. How did you define $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in your class?

Comment: Zp is defined as just an integer n, then mod p how you showed it. n (mod p). By the way is my part C correct there, and thank you for the complete answer and help that you provide!